# Unusual SQL Server Query Result

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I faced with an unusual query result while running a sql server query.

The important table to note is **Code_Structure_Type**.
It contains columns **Code_Structure_Type_Id smallint, Name char(50)** and few other columns that are not used here.

My Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.A1_Id                    AS Code_Unit_Attribute_Id,
                A1.Name                     AS Code_Unit_Attribute_Name,
                Code_Structure_Type.A1_Name AS Code_Attribute_Type
--, Code_Structure_Type.Code_Structure_Type_Id 
FROM   Defect
       INNER JOIN Defect_Code_Unit
         ON Defect.Defect_Id = Defect_Code_Unit.Defect_Id
       INNER JOIN Code_Unit
         ON Defect_Code_Unit.Code_Unit_Id = Code_Unit.Code_Unit_Id
       INNER JOIN A1
         ON Code_Unit.A1_Id = A1.A1_Id
       INNER JOIN ERA_Module
         ON Defect.ERA_Module_Id = ERA_Module.ERA_Module_Id
       INNER JOIN Code_Unit_Type
         ON Code_Unit.Code_Unit_Type_Id = Code_Unit_Type.Code_Unit_Type_Id
       INNER JOIN Code_Structure_Type
         ON Code_Unit_Type.Code_Structure_Type_Id = Code_Structure_Type.Code_Structure_Type_Id
WHERE  ERA_Module.ERA_Project_Id = 472
       AND ERA_Module.Is_Active = 1
       AND Defect.Is_Closed = 0
       AND Defect_Code_Unit.Is_Active = 1
       AND Code_Structure_Type.Name = 'Pega Rules'
       --AND Code_Structure_Type.Code_Structure_Type_Id = 2 
       AND A1.A1_Id > 0
       AND Code_Unit.Scope_Id = 1
```

This query returns me with a single row which is incorrent. The expected result of this query should be none because we **do not have Defects for 'Pega Rules' Code_Structure_Type**.

If I uncomment this line

```
--, Code_Structure_Type.Code_Structure_Type_Id
```

I get no results which is correct.

Also if I filter from the Code_Structure_Type_Id which is for 'Pega Rules' not with Code_Structure_Type.Name I get the correct result as well which is none.
To do this I uncomment this line

```
--AND Code_Structure_Type.Code_Structure_Type_Id = 2
```

and comment this line

```
AND Code_Structure_Type.Name = 'Pega Rules'
```

So basically I'm doing the same thing and there is no other name like 'Pega Rules' in the table Code_Structure_Type, not even close. Only five rows are there in that table.

I need to understand what is happening here.

Thanks in advance.

#### Links to Execution Plans

Files, when used 'pega rules' only - [incorrect_original.xml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oJzRNZe005cmNjckRFTnA5ZFE/edit) when used 'pega rules' + select - [correct_with_added_select.xml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oJzRNZe005b0ZoMDFNN0VFMTA/edit) when used id - [correct_with_Id.xml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oJzRNZe005Q0kyQ0dGU0h6elk/edit)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 version.

Comment: So you uncomment a line in the `SELECT` list and that makes the result go from 1 row to 0 rows? Are these all plain tables or are you using any views or computed columns? If you are using views or computed columns do they have any non deterministic constructs in them? If they are all tables please post the XML for the actual execution plans for both queries.

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith,

Thank you for you reply.

All the tables I am using are plain tables no views or computed columns are used.

I will share the execution plan XMLs with you.

Thank you in advance.

Files,
when used 'pega rules' only  - [incorrect_original.xml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oJzRNZe005cmNjckRFTnA5ZFE/edit?usp=sharing)

when used 'pega rules' + select  - [correct_with_added_select.xml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oJzRNZe005b0ZoMDFNN0VFMTA/edit?usp=sharing)

when used id - [correct_with_Id.xml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oJzRNZe005Q0kyQ0dGU0h6elk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Akalanka, I probably won't get a chance to look at these until this evening. I'll edit the links into the question to bump it and maybe someone else will have it resolved by then!

Comment: But I just had a quick look and please provide the actual execution plans not estimated. The whole point of asking was to see where the actual row count diverges between the plans and it is not possible to see this in the estimated plan.

Comment: oh sorry @Martin, will have the access to that db only by the next week. I'll upload the actual execution plans then. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I've been trying to get the actual execution plan. But now it seems that all three queries give me the correct result. I have added actual execution plan for the given query. But I won't think it will be of much use now. [Actual](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0oJzRNZe005NW9xRkJuZ0dUcGc/edit?usp=sharing)